# How to convert MERN app to mobile app using any framework

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, phonegap, mern

I enjoy MERN development and I actually prefer it to Meteor, etc.

With Meteor however, it is pretty convenient to convert the website into a mobile app with a few commands.

I was wondering if there is anyway to convert a MERN website into a mobile app using one of the "wrappers" available like PhoneGap, etc.?

What options do I have?
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "Cordova" of Apache which is a mobile application development framework. This will help you port the web application to different mobile platform.